# anchor element click event

Tags: gwt, click, anchor

I have been using uibinder for a while and got pretty good at it. I know all about the use of HTMLPanel and Anchor for adding click handlers. However, there are cases where this design approach simply doesn't fit the bill.

say I have a unordered list, and each list has some anchor elements.

```
<ul><li><a ...></li>...</ul>
```

it is good to make each li as a component (java class) so you can add multiple instances of the component inside the ul. this means inside the ui.xml, you start with li (no other way that I can see). but then there is no way to insert Anchor inside. you can not replace li with HTMLPanel since that would create a div which you don't want.

by leave the anchor as a in this uibinder, there would be no way to detect the anchor click event.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML, set ID to the anchor :

```
<a id='testachor'>...</a>
```

In your GWT code, wrap the anchor into a widget:

```
Anchor testAnchor = Anchor.wrap(Document.getElementById('testanchor'));
```

Then add click handler to it:

```
testAnchor.addDomHandler(new ClickHandler(){...}, ClickEvent.getType());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add Anchor widget inside `<li>` tag:

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <g:Anchor ui:field="link" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```